# Several table of content's items not showing in the hyperlink menu

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

I want to hyperlink to a certain chapter somewhere in my book.

It works fine for some chapters but for some reason [Chapters 1, 2, 3, 4 and 7 are not shown.](https://puu.sh/xS4Ut/b75a3b964f.png)

[Here's](https://puu.sh/xS4Xa/9c1c685b59.png) the original table of content.

What's seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem was that missing chapters' titles didn't have proper styles.

The problem was fixed when I made all the missing chapters' titles Heading 1.